# Best way to query Azure blob storage by multiple metadata items

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on some code to query azure blob storage by passing in a X number of metadata key/value pairs.

I have this code right now to search for one:

```
            BlobContainerClient container = GetBlobContainerForDownloads(blobContainerClient);

            var blobItems = GetAllBlobsForContainer(container);

            if (blobItems == null)
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<AzureStorageFileDownloadResultDTO>();
            }

            IList<AzureStorageFileDownloadResultDTO> results = new List<AzureStorageFileDownloadResultDTO>();

            AzureStorageFileDownloadResultDTO result;

            foreach (var item in blobItems.Where(w => w.Metadata.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(FileManagerMetadataContants.ModuleType, moduleType.ToString())) == true && w.Metadata.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(metaDataKey, metaDataValue)) == true && w.Metadata.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(FileManagerMetadataContants.IsFileDeleted, FileManagerMetadataContants.IsFileDeletedValue)) == false))
            {
                result = new AzureStorageFileDownloadResultDTO()
                {
                    FileData = null, // do not pull the file data when returning all the files ; the developer will return back to the API to get the actual file with the blob name
                    FileFound = true,
                    BlobName = item.Name,
                    FileName = GetFileName(item.Metadata),
                    FileNameWithExtension = GetFileNameWithExtension(item.Metadata),
                    ContentType = item.Properties.ContentType,
                    FileExtension = item.Properties.ContentType,
                    MetaData = item.Metadata
                };

                results.Add(result);
            }
```

This could be slow in time.

What is the best way to query multiple metadata key/value pairs?

Comment: I update a link with video, which would be better to understand, you could check it. @ttaylor27272727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider searching Blob meta data using Azure Search, which is more efficient.

Here is the official tutorial:

[How to configure a blob indexer in Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage)

[Search over Azure Blob storage content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-blob-storage-integration)

You could also do it on portal through create **Azure Search** service:
[image]
You could follow with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQDRNQD1LDk).